# removeClass is not working if href exist in anchor

Tags: php, jquery, html, removeclass

I have a html look like this

```
<tr>  
    <td style="padding:0px;">
        <a class="list-group-item active change_class" href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tester/projectwise_issue_list_display/".$row->project_id;?>"><?php echo $row->project_name;?></a>
    </td> 
    <td style="padding:0px;">
        <a class="list-group-item active change_class" href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/tester/projectwise_issue_list_display/".$row->project_id;?>"><?php echo $row->project_name;?></a>
    </td> 
</tr>
```

When I click on the anchor it's not removing my class.

jquery is below....

```
jQuery('td').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('a').removeClass('change_class');
});
```

If I remove href from anchor it's nicely working. I need removeClass with href

Comment: can you show the output code

Answer (score 2):

Just Change Script like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('td').click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();  
      jQuery(this).find('a').removeClass('change_class');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Does that actually work? The link is a child of the table-cell, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't think it does, you can prevent the event from bubbling up from the link to a parent element, but not the other way around. See for example here and move the `e.stopPropagation();` around: http://jsbin.com/deludawawe/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

You should call your `click` event on the anchor tag itself.

```
jQuery('td > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    jQuery(this).removeClass('change_class');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for removing class from the anchors and you want to have navigation functionality too. Then you have to do this on `ready` event in a common js file:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').removeClass('change_class');
});
```

What it is doing, when user clicks the anchor user gets navigated to the specified href. Navigation results in a page load so we put it directly inside a `ready` event. It removes the class if the `href` of anchor is same as `window.location.href`.

Comment: @user7149801 glad this helped you.

Comment: @user7149801 if it resolved your issue then you can look it as an answer to your question via accepting with clicking the green tick.